# How to roll over time past 24:00

Tags: mysql, time

I want to at add 12 hrs to the time 430pm(16:30) but when I do so, instead of going to 04:30 it is going to 28:30 how would i get it to roll over to  00:00 and then to 04:30.

```
select ADDTIME('16:00:00', '12:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a random date to the time i.e `2014-01-01 16:30:00`, then use a combination of [ADDTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) and [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function. The first step is adding 12 hours to `2014-01-01 16:30:00` as below

```
SELECT ADDTIME('2014-01-01 16:30:00', '0 12:0:0');
```

The result of the above syntax is `2014-01-02 04:30:00`, then you need to take the time part of the result

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-01-02 04:30:00', '%H:%i:%s');
```

so you will get `04:30:00` as expected.

Below is the combined syntax of the above that produces the same result

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME('2014-01-01 16:30:00', '0 12:0:0'), '%H:%i:%s');
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/47202/0)</kbd>